# Run Query of Wordpress in a Button Javascript - WPDB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to run a JavaScript function to javascript sending `$variables` when running a single button, but not how to make the connection of `$wpdb` from JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/writing-custom-queries-in-wordpress--wp-25510

**For example:**

```
$wpdb->update(
    'foods',
    array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',  // string
        'year' =>  'value2'  // integer (number)
    ),
    array( 'ID' => 1 ),
    array(
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ),
    array( '%d' )
);
```

When you press a button in the event `onClick` Query will run in JavaScript but not how to make the connection with the base to give you to run the query.

Comment: You can't directly interface with `$wpdb` (and server side code in general) in javascript. You'll need to make an ajax request to the server, which can then respond with the data you require. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins